# How to test whether gif images like 'Loading' are working or not?

Tags: javascript, css

I coded my page such that a GIF image is displayed until the web page is completely loaded. Now I'd like to test it whether it is working correctly or not. For this I need to make my web page to load slowly!! But I am not having any idea to make the web page load slowly! What can I do for a web page to load slowly? Please help me!!

Comment: Well you COULD let it load some big video file (through html5 <video>), but you might as well just check the file location. If you want to check the loader itself (not just the gif) - just implement a wait function to stop the js loader from displaying the page, e.g. jquery's .delay(): http://api.jquery.com/delay/.

Answer (score 4):

You could load it via a proxy. Most of the ones on public lists are incredibly slow.
Here you can find some: http://www.samair.ru/proxy/time-01.htm
Good luck.

Comment: Hey , please help me! How can I load via a proxy? I don't know @bytelab

Comment: That depends on your browser. Here are links to tutroials of the most used browsers:
Firefox - http://www.wikihow.com/Enter-Proxy-Settings-in-Firefox
Opera - http://fwptt.sourceforge.net/ProxyHowTo/OperaProxySettings.htm
Chrome - http://customers.trustedproxies.com/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=10
Safari - http://customers.trustedproxies.com/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=15
You can use the proxy list i posted above or simply google some. The standard format is x.x.x.x:y.
For further reading (simplified): http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/proxy-server
Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Add some server-side `delay` into your page. I assume that you're using a standard hosting provider or using your computer as a localhost and in both cases you have some form of server-side scripting.

In PHP you can do it like this:

```
<?php 
sleep(20);    // 20 sec delay 
?>
```

Add it in the end of page, when at least your GIF animation has already sent to the client.

I'm not really sure, but you might be able to do the same using Javascript's `setTimeout` also.

P.S. I know that the original post didn't mention server-side scripting at all, however I assume it's possible for him/her to achieve it.